# Set the duration of an ffmpeg overlay transition using lavfi

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command to slide an overlayed image off of a black background and to the right.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=color=black:d=15:size=1920x1080,format=rgba[background]; movie=pinkimage.png[overlay]; [background][overlay]overlay='min(n*5-0\,1920):(H-h)/2'" output.mp4
```

I am understanding that it is the manipulation of the "n" parameter that affects the speed of the transition, but I don't understand why or how.  I would like it to do so for the length of the video which is 15 seconds as set here with: "d=15".

So, how can I do something like make the overlay animation take 15 seconds as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` in the expression refers to the frame index (starting from 0).

`min(n*5-0\,1920)` is the expression for the x co-ordinate. For each frame, this expression is evaluated, and its result is used for the x-position of the top-left corner of the overlay frame. The position is measured from the top-left of the background/base frame. The min function returns the minimum of its two arguments. For the given expression, you are moving 5 pixels right each frame, starting from x=0 at the start. So to travel 1920 pixels, it will take 1920/5 = 380 frames. For a 25 fps video, that's 15.2 seconds.

To reach in 15 seconds, you can set the expression as follows, `t*1920/15`.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=color=black:d=15:size=1920x1080,format=rgba -i pinkimage.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x='t*1920/15':y='(H-h)/2'" output.mp4
```